# Automated web scraping in R for more values

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I have this code for web scraping in R using Rselenium. It works for a static example.
But I want to make it works for more inputs. Let's say I have a data frame in R named `Data` with 2 columns: one for `CNP` and one for `VIN` with `1000 rows`. How can I scraping in this case? I tried with `option$sendKeysToElement(Data$CNP)` but didn't work. I tried also with a `for` sentence, no result, just errors.

This is my code:

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"),port = 4444L,chromever = "83.0.4103.39") #specify browser type you want Selenium to open
remDr <- rD$client
#remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://test2.wais.groupama.ro/bdrcas/bdr_cas/bdr_cas_operatii/istoric") # navigates to webpage

# select first input field
option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="BdrCasCnp")
option$highlightElement()
option$clickElement()
option$sendKeysToElement(list("29902999202"))

# select second input field
option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="BdrCasVin")
option$highlightElement()
option$clickElement()
option$sendKeysToElement(list("UU1KSDAFH36474825"))

#press key
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', "#BdrCasIstoricForm > div.row > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > button > span:nth-child(1)")
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$clickElement()

text <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "BdrCasIstoricForm")
x = text$getElementText()
print(x)
```

I have to say that the `url` is private.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the for loop and read row by row your input and replace them.

**I can't try the code below because I don't have the web site link!!**

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"),port = 4444L,chromever = "83.0.4103.39") #specify browser type you want Selenium to open
remDr <- rD$client
#remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://test2.wais.groupama.ro/bdrcas/bdr_cas/bdr_cas_operatii/istoric") # navigates to webpage


Data#your data frame!


my_data_scrape<-data.frame()
for (i in 1:1000) {

# select first input field
option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="BdrCasCnp")
option$highlightElement()
option$clickElement()
first_element_to_send<-as.charachert(Data$CNP[i])
option$sendKeysToElement(list(first_element_to_send))

Sys.sleep(1) #My expirience tell me that we need a bit break

#select second input field
option <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value="BdrCasVin")
option$highlightElement()
option$clickElement()
secondo_element_to_send<-as.charachert(Data$VIN[i])
option$sendKeysToElement(list(secondo_element_to_send))

Sys.sleep(1) #My expirience tell me that we need a bit break

#press key
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', "#BdrCasIstoricForm > div.row > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > button > span:nth-child(1)")
webElem$highlightElement()
webElem$clickElement()
text <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "BdrCasIstoricForm")
x = text$getElementText()
my_data_scrape<-rbind(my_data_scrape,x)

print(my_data_scrape)

remDr$navigate("https://test2.wais.groupama.ro/bdrcas/bdr_cas/bdr_cas_operatii/istoric")

Sys.sleep(3) #I don't know if 3 senconds are enough!!
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed the error. The problem was with my data format. The column `CNP` was `number` and the right format for web scraping is `character`. After that I did a simple `for` sentence and all good. Yes, you can't access the site because is private.

Comment: At this stage you should write the answer if my answer doesn't fix the problem.